# Swift - Print the name of a variable?

Tags: swift

I have some variables defined:

```
let purpleSquareCategory:   UInt32 = 1 << 0
let circleCategory:         UInt32 = 1 << 1
let blueSquareCategory:     UInt32 = 1 << 2
let edgeCategory:           UInt32 = 1 << 31
```

later in my code, I have temporary variable with one of these values in it e.g.

```
let x = nodeCategory
```

Is there any way that I print a message saying which of my pre-defined categories x is? e.g.

```
print("x is variable zzz")
```

where zzz is purpleSquareCategory, circleCategory etc

Personally, I can't see that it can be done  because that would have to be resolved at runtime and the variable names aren't available then.

Could I achieve what I want by some other means? e.g. using an enum or some other type for my categories?

I'm trying to write a stand-alone helper function, designed to be dropped into any Swift program that using collisions and/or contacts, so If can't write:

```
if category == purpleSquareCategory {print("Purple Square")}
if category == circleCategory {print("Circle")}
```

because in my function, I don't know what categories have been defined.

Comment: Take a look at `OptionSetType`. It's dedicated for bit shifted constants.

Comment: But is either of these tips going to allow me to print the name of the variable that has the matching category?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve what you want. What I know you can do is to check the type of the variable you are using: Mirror(reflecting: item).subjectType.

Comment: You cannot print variable names directly but with `OptionSetType` you can check if a value matches a particular bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

What about this as a solution :) or am I missing something here?

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let purpleSquareCategory:   UInt32 = 1 << 0
let circleCategory:         UInt32 = 1 << 1
let blueSquareCategory:     UInt32 = 1 << 2
let edgeCategory:           UInt32 = 1 << 31
print("\(purpleSquareCategory)")
let x = circleCategory
switch (x) {
  case purpleSquareCategory:
  print("purple")
  break
case circleCategory:
  print("circle")
  break
case blueSquareCategory:
  print("blue")
  break
case edgeCategory:
  print("edge")
  break
default:
  break
}
```

Comment: No good - my function is designed to be dropped I to a program experiencing difficulties and called without modification, so you can't add such a structure to it.

Comment: What I want to do is to print which variables in the program have a certain value by discovering the names of the variables programmatically. I've done it in interpreted languages, but I can't see how it can be done for a compiled language.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was just too easy; what about the logic operators like & and | to and said variables; you might get away with a more compact solution? They are after all, bitmaps no? They are 1, 2, 4 and what 2147483648.

Comment: Well, thanks for trying. I can do do enough in my helper function to indicate that *something* is wrong; the user can then do a bit of investigation to establish what exactly.